# Conversion of Looping to Recursive Solution

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion, pythagorean

I have written a method `pythagoreanTriplets` in scala using nested loops. As a newbie in scala, I am struggling with how can we do the same thing using recursion and use Lazy Evaluation for the returning list(List of tuples). Any help will be highly appreciated.

***P.S: The following method is working perfectly fine.***

```
// This method returns the list of all pythagorean triples whose components are
// at most a given limit. Formula a^2 + b^2 = c^2

def pythagoreanTriplets(limit: Int): List[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
    // triplet: a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    var (a,b,c,m) = (0,0,0,2)
    var triplets:List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List()
    while (c < limit) {
      breakable {
        for (n <- 1 until m) {
          a = m * m - n * n
          b = 2 * m * n
          c = m * m + n * n
          if (c > limit)
            break
          triplets = triplets :+ (a, b, c)
        }
        m += 1
      }
    }// end of while
    triplets
  }
```

Comment: For `pythagoreanTriplets(10)` it would return this list -->  `[(3, 4, 5), (4, 3, 5), (6, 8, 10), (8, 6,10)]`

Comment: Can you show us your best attempt to write it yourself using recursion and lazy evaluation? Then we can see where you got stuck, see what kind of help you actually need, and hopefully help you get it across the finish line.

Comment: You say your "method is working perfectly fine" but the output of `pythagoreanTriplets(38)` is missing the `(35,12,37)` triplet.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see where recursion would offer significant advantages.

```
def pythagoreanTriplets(limit: Int): List[(Int, Int, Int)] = 
  for {
    m <- (2 to limit/2).toList
    n <- 1 until m
    c =  m*m + n*n if c <= limit
  } yield (m*m - n*n, 2*m*n, c)
```