# Trying to Pattern match an integer argument "globally" within a function - Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, unfold

First of all I apologize if the title of this is misleading, its based off what I think my issue might be. I am creating a lazy list of tuples, the end goal is to find **all pythagorean triples** with values less than or equal to n and rather than create all possible combination of 'triples', I have gone for this approach which I **think** is more efficient but might be overkill, however, it works :)

```
  val n = 20
  val increasingTriplets  = unfold(Option(1, 1, 1)) {
    case None => None
    case Some(current) =>
      val maybeNext = current match {
        case (`n`, `n`, `n`) => None
        case (x, `n`, `n`) => Some(x + 1, x + 1, x + 1)
        case (x, y, `n`) => Some(x, y + 1, y + 1)
        case (x, y, z) => Some(x, y, z + 1) // (1,1,1) , (1,1,2), (1,1,3)...etc
      }
      Some(current, maybeNext)
  }.take(nCr(`n`+3-1,3).toInt).filter({ // The formula for the number of combinations with repetition -
    case (a,b,c) => a*a + b*b == c*c    // - allowed of  objects from  types is  +−1C
                                       // Ensures minimum number of lists is always generated(I think)
  })    

    println(unfold_with_pythcomp(increasingTriplets,pythcomp).toList)
    // n = 20 List((3,4,5), (4,3,5), (5,12,13), (12,5,13), (6,8,10)
    List((3,4,5), (4,3,5), (5,12,13), (12,5,13), (6,8,10), (8,6,10),
   (8,15,17), (15,8,17), (9,12,15), (12,9,15), (12,16,20), (16,12,20))

    // n = 10
    List((3,4,5), (4,3,5), (6,8,10), (8,6,10))


  // Implementation of unfold

  def unfold[A, S](z: S)(f: S => Option[(A, S)]): LazyList[A] =
    f(z).map((p: (A, S)) => p._1 #:: unfold(p._2)(f)).getOrElse(LazyList.empty[A])

  def unfold_with_pythcomp[A](l1: LazyList[A], f: A => Option[(A, A)]): LazyList[A] =
  // unfolds result list appending the "complement"
    l1 match {
      case LazyList() => l1
      case x #:: y => f(x) match {
        case Some((l, r)) => l #:: r #:: unfold_with_pythcomp(y, f)
      }
    }

  def pythcomp(t: (Int, Int, Int)): Option[((Int, Int, Int), (Int, Int, Int))] = t match {
      //Creates a "complement" to add since (3,4,5) <-> (4,3,5)
    case (a, b, c) => Some((a, b, c), (b, a, c))
  }

  def fact(n: Int): BigInt = { // These are just for efficiency, you may ignore
    @tailrec def go(n: Int, acc: BigInt): BigInt =
      if (n <= 0) acc
      else go(n - 1, BigInt(n) * acc)
    go(n, 1)

  }
  def nCr(n: Int, r: Int): BigInt = { // These are just for efficiency, you may ignore
    fact(n)/(fact(n-r) * fact(r))
  }
```

Now I am trying to make this into a function that would do the exact same thing while taking just n as an argument which might be really simple, however I have been running into issues trying to pattern match the given n argument. This is what I came up with so far:

```
  def unfold_remix[Int](`n`: Int): LazyList[Option[(Int, Int, Int)]] =
  // not sure if I can use backticks here
    unfold(Option(1, 1, 1)) {
      case None => None
      case Some(current) =>
        // Problem could also be from here.
        val maybeNext = current match {
          case (`n`, `n`, `n`) => None
          case (x, `n`, `n`) => Some(x + 1, x + 1, x + 1)
          case (x, y, `n`) => Some(x, y + 1, y + 1)
          case (x, y, z) => Some(x, y, z + 1) // (1,1,1) , (1,1,2), (1, 1,3)...1st
        }
        Some(current, **maybeNext**)
      // I get an error on this line under maybeNext.
      // Too many arguments for method apply(A)
    }
```

I keep getting an error when trying to initialize the list as I had done earlier and being a beginner to Scala I can't seem to understand why. I have tried the argument with and without backticks and that did not work either. Wondering if it would be possible for someone to help me figure problem out and also I'd like to know if its possible to pattern match a given integer argument "globally" within a function.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60469775/4993128)?

Comment: Yes I have, thank you @jwvh. The aim of my post is to discover the source of error in my approach if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this returns the correct results but it compiles (the types check).

```
def unfold_remix(n: Int): LazyList[Option[(Int, Int, Int)]] =
  unfold(Option(1, 1, 1)) {
    case None => None
    case Some(current) =>
      val maybeNext = current match {
        case (`n`, `n`, `n`) => None
        case (x, `n`, `n`) => Some(x + 1, x + 1, x + 1)
        case (x, y, `n`) => Some(x, y + 1, y + 1)
        case (x, y, z) => Some(x, y, z + 1)
      }
      Some((Some(current), maybeNext))
  }
```

(And, yes, this is way too much code for a relatively simple task.)